# Custom NewForm & EditForm for Lists in app web of sharepoint-hosted apps

Tags: list, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

My goal is to create a custom NewForm and EditForm for an existing SharePoint list in the app web of a sharepoint-hosted app for SharePoint 2013 online using Visual Studio 2013. In addition to a custom layout, the forms should also use custom JavaScript.

I have read and worked through several tutorials like

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2011/05/12/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-how-to-create-a-customized-list-edit-form-for-development-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

This tutorial requires to open the list in SharePoint Designer. My question now: How can I open and edit lists of the app web in SharePoint Designer (I am working with SharePoint Designer 2013)? Is it even possible? Or is there another possibility to create a custom NewForm and EditForm for a list in the app web of a sharepoint-hosted app for SharePoint 2013 online using Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you dont.

What you need insted is to look into Client Side Rendering, and manipulate your newform by JavaScript insted.

This is an older question, so if it is still relevant, and if you need help moving forward let me know, and i will be happy to elaborate.